# Float sequence breaks in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-float, media-queries

I have a confusing anomaly with my floats that only happens in Firefox and seemingly only with the 3rd float of the sequence.

I have a row of floats (currently 9), that responsively switch from 3 per line to 2 per line. All the floats have exactly the same class so there isn't any obvious reason this one should act out. I have tried moving the floats round to see if it's one particular box - but it's always the 3rd and only in firefox.

My site isn't finished but I have put it up on shereewalker.com to help see the issue as well as some code below.

The issue happens when the screen is moved down to a two image row rather than 3 (700px break point).

The images also flash a little when changing but I can live with that.

Any ideas? I'm just a beginner at this stuff and it's very strange and frustrating.

Thanks in advance

Basic html - repeated multiple times

```
    <div class="flex_one">
         <a><img class="icon-image" src="images/new/thumb_adtc.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex_one">
         <a><img class="icon-image" src="images/new/thumb_adtc.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the css

```
.icon-image {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 900ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 900ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 900ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 900ms ease;
    transition: all 900ms ease;
}


@media screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:700px) {

.flex_one {
    width:44%;
    height:auto;    
    float:left;
    border: solid 2px rgb(0,81,88);
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-top:4%;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease;
    -o-transition: 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s ease;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;


}

}



/*/////////////3 COLUMN LAYOUT///////////// */


@media screen and (min-width:701px) {


.flex_one {
    width:28%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
    border: solid 2px rgb(0,81,88);
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-top:4%;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease;
    -o-transition: 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s ease;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please provide a reproducible example in the question. As I see it, there is no problem. -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/zm9u39uq/

Comment: Can you look at shereewalker.com in Firefox?
The problem is there is no problem..... it works perfectly, as far as I see, the code is good, as per your jsfiddle... until you open it in firefox. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about difference of your image dimension. If all your images width and height values will be same, it will be ok!

Comment: I tried this and while the sequence flows properly, the images need to respond proportionately, therefore I can't have a fixed height, they distort :(

Comment: I get the issue. It's all about your % width values. If you try the edited answer, it will be ok!

Comment: Can you explain sorry? The 44% width was so 2 x 44 = 88, plus three margins at 4% is 100%. does it not require a full 100%?. Sorry - thanks again!

Comment: Some calculation problem may cause because of using fluid layout. For example It can be perfect for 100px container width but when container will be -for example-112 px,  %44 calculation will be 2.5px or 2.6px.

Comment: Okay - I have just been reading about browser rounding, so I understand better. I will try slightly less than 100% for Firefox browser now. Thank you!

Comment: Okay so it hasn't worked. Back to the drawing board. Thanks though.

Comment: I checked your site again and i figured that, flex_one class heights are different because of img inside. Please check the height value or give a specific height flex_one class just for trying.

Comment: It worked! I probably seem stupid now but I never thought the img sizes would matter as they are supposed to scale to the containing boxes - which ARE all the same size. I can't say I really understand but I'm very relieved. Thank you very much - if you post that as an answer not a comment I'll select it :)

Comment: Also - this has stopped the images flickering when resizing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88817/discussion-between-guvenckardas-and-sheree-walker).